# Mult-Language support using Resource File

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, multilingual

I am trying to allow my program to be used in different language. 
I have a resource file named language_en.

During runtime, I would like to change the value of each strings in language_en.

I've created .ini file that holds all the strings in language_en, as well as the controls on the form. Using that file during load, I am easily able to change the text of controls. Such as: Text of Button1 from "Yes" to "Ja".

I am not able to do the same for resource file since it is read-only. I know one way I could do is to create multiple resource file for each language. However, I'de like to be able to do it all within the .ini file.

I was trying something like this:

```
ResourceSet RSet = English.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(
                        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);

foreach (DictionaryEntry Entry in RSet)
{
    Entry.Value = ? 
}
```

but obviously it wont work, not only because I am trying to modify a collection during iteration, but since the value is readonly.

Anyone have idea what approach I could take?

P.S. Where should I define my Application.CultureInfo? Before InitializeComponent()?

Comment: What is wrong with just having the different resource files for each language?

Comment: I've created a program that lets user translate english into their own native language. That program generates everything in .ini format. I would only like to use that file, rather then me having to create different resource files. I have over 70 strings in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct way to do this in .NET is creating multiple resource files as follows:

Say you have resource file Resource.resx, it will serve as default English words for your UI, Now if you wish to add support for Spanish language, then just add a resource file named Resource.es.resx(this file will contains exact same keys as the original file but values will be Spanish translations) in the same directory. Whenever user change system language to Spanish .NET will automatically utilize correct resource file. Similarly you can add support for as many languages as you want just by adding resource file with correct extension.

Comment: Yea, I'm aware of that possibility. I guess that will be my last resort. I just wanted to try and get it all done from the .ini file.

Comment: I just suggested the most recommended way, and believe me it makes maintenance really easy. Initially we had support for 2 languages and recently we added 3 more language and it was so easy. At last decision is yours depending on your requirement.

Comment: Well our .ini files generated like this: Item|(Text), Value|(Text)... I didn't want to manually add those lines to a resource file, hence the .ini. I just realize now that I can just create a simple program that gets the .ini file and builds a .resx out of it. I guess this might be way i'll be going then.

Comment: That brings me to another question, how do I change the resource file from language_en.resx to language_fr.resx? Let's say users culture is English, however, he would like to view it in French. How do we change the default resx being used?

Comment: You don't do that. Its logically incorrect. It works on your system wide settings, if your system's language is french then your application should show French not English or anything else. If you still need to do that, then this will not be a suitable approach for you.

Comment: I don't see why not. If the user's computer's language is English, and he wants to view the program in French (Since it is available), he should be able to do so. Anyway, I've accomplished it by changing the Current Culture by Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr");